# What should I do when some users can see my NTFS drives, and others can't?

Tags: 10.04, mount, ntfs, users

Hi I have two NTFS drive partitions that I want to be able to access from either Windows or Ubuntu 10.04, and it works fine...from MY account.

When any of the other Ubuntu accounts are logged in, they can't see the drives.  They are invisible to other users both before and after I mount them in my account.

I looked at the permissions tab for the drives and it says the permissions cannot be determined.  Maybe that's normal for a Windows drive, I don't know.

I tried searching for an answer but it I can't find anybody else that asked the same thing.

What should I do?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you specify how do you mount the partition? Through nautilus or through `fstab`? In the second case, post the exact line in `fstab`.

Comment: Could it be a permission issue?.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, then please flag explaining that (as well as editing your question with any details you have).

Answer (score 0):

How about installing ntfs-config? It's a GUI utility to assist in mounting NTFS drives automatically during bootup.

Start a package manager, search for ntfs, install. You'll find the program in System tools.

Answer (score 0):

If some Microsoft computers can see your computer and others can't. That tells me that the configuration on your computer is ok. On the systems that can't see your computer check to see if they are setup already for having a home network. If they are Configured already . and still having same issue and if they are Windows 7 look in administration tools encryption if its set to 256 change it to 128 this was a issue with Ubuntu 10.10 . Ubuntu 11.04 may have same issue worth a try. and remember reboot after and changes you make to configure.